# will database pull whole table at once or one row by one row after using model.objects.all().iterator() in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I know django will return the model object one by one after using `iterator()` on queryset to save memory. In database side, will django pull the data one row by one row or still pull the whole table at once just like model.objects.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated. The query selects all records from the database. The best way to figure this out is to add 'backend' DEBUG level logging in your settings, and you can see the actual SQL queries that are being executed.